# PHP/MySQL: Move data from old database (tables without an ID) to new database (tables with an ID)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function which gets me all tables with their columns from an old database to a new database. Everything is working fine so far. Now I need to extend that function, so that in all tables inside my new database a surrogate key (primary key ID with auto increment) will be added.

Old DB:

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
|               Col1                |    Col2    | NumCol |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
| Value 1                           | Value 2    |    123 |
| This is a row with only one cell  |            |        |
| This row is testing html entities | Te<br />st |     45 |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
```

New DB:

```
+----+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
| ID |               Col1                |    Col2    | NumCol |
+----+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
|  1 | Value 1                           | Value 2    |    123 |
|  2 | This is a row with only one cell  |            |        |
|  3 | This row is testing html entities | Te<br />st |     45 |
+----+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
```

So as you can see, everything remains the same except the new column ID in every table.

Here is my function to copy everything from my old DB to my new DB:

```
public function loadOldDBtoNewDB($oldDB,$newDB){
    $sqlshowTables = "SHOW TABLES ";
    $statement = $this->db->prepare($sqlshowTables);
    $statement->execute();
    $tables = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

    foreach($tables as $table){
        $sql[] = "INSERT INTO ".$newDB.".`".$table[0]."` SELECT * FROM ".$oldDB.".`".$table[0]."`; ";
    }

    $sqlState = implode(' ', $sql);
    $executeStatement = $this->db->exec($sqlState);

}
```

**Note:** Old DB and new DB already exist when I run this function.

So how do I need to change my inser statement so that an ID (auto increment) column will be added during every insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new table should already have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` on the `id` column. Then supply a `NULL` value to it when doing the select!

If your new table doesn't have auto-increment set on the `ID` column, add it by

```sql
ALTER TABLE `mytablename` 
CHANGE `ID` `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Add a `NULL` before the `*` in your `SELECT` - this will force the `ID` (which appears first in your column-list) to use the `AUTO_INCREMENT`, since it cannot be `NULL`.

```php
$sql[] = "INSERT INTO ".$newDB.".`".$table[0]."` SELECT NULL, * FROM ".$oldDB.".`".$table[0]."`; ";
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me into the right direction. Your answer is correct and I will mark it as accepted answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

u can also create new table with following command

```
create table new_table as (select * from old_table);

alter table new_table add column id primary key auto_increment;
```

Comment: thanks your answer is also correct. @Qirel was a tick faster therefore I will mark his answer as accepted answer.